# How do I create a fade-out transition with a WPF border on mouse hover?

Tags: c#, wpf, border, mouseevent

I am trying to create a `Border` that shows/hides the border itself on hover.  The desired effect is to show a border around content on hover and when the mouse leaves the area, the border fades out.  I can't figure out the "fading out" part.

The snippet below uses style `Trigger`s.  It works as far as toggling the border color.  How can I achieve the fade-out?

```
<Border
    BorderThickness="1"
    >
    <Border.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger
                    Property="Border.IsMouseOver"
                    Value="false">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Border.BorderBrush"
                        Value="Transparent" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger
                    Property="Border.IsMouseOver"
                    Value="true">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Border.BorderBrush"
                        Value="LightGray" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
```

Comment: Have you tried using blend? You could create a rectangle with a transparent center. Set the border color, then create a storyboard animation that makes it fade in on hover.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try using a `ColorAnimation`

something like:

```
<Border.Style>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="Transparent" />
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                Value="True">
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
              <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.01"
                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color"
                              To="LightGray" />
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
        <Trigger.ExitActions>
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
              <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.6"
                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color"
                              To="Transparent" />
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.ExitActions>
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</Border.Style>
```